# How to create a 1d list with a .txt that has \n?

Tags: python, list

I want to read in a a text file and put every element of the file into one list instead of having a separate list for every line in the file. So for example, if the file was:

Hello my name

Is Joe

I want the list to be [Hello my name Is Joe] instead of

[[Hello my name] [is Joe]]

Here's what I have so far

```
 def evaluate_essay():
        fileList= []
        file= open("text1.txt", "r")
        fileList= [line.rstrip()  for line in file]
        file.close()
        fileList=[item.split(" ") for item in fileList]
        print (fileList)
```

Comment: Your example desired output `[Hello my name Is Joe]` is not a valid Python expression. Just what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the entire file and split on whitespace:

```
with open("text1.txt", "r") as f:
    file_list = f.read().split()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: that's the faster way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can read the lines in a list comprehension with a double for loop to split the words:

```
def evaluate_essay():
        with open("text1.txt", "r") as f:
            words = [w for l in f for w in l.split()]
```